# Any high quality form plugins?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, forms

There are so many, and I've literally tried at least 10. None are quite right. I don't want one with all this "ajax" stuff. I just want something that validates the input server side, can handle multiple forms, and allows the fields to be customized.

All the plugins that I've tried thus far require way too much hacking and styling to get them to look alright. They try to be "cool" by saying "oh look this plugin has ajax". I honestly wouldn't mind ajax in the plugin if it is progressively enhanced and not too styled already.

*preferably free of course

Answer (score 5):

Gravity Forms. Gravity Forms. Gravity Forms.

http://www.gravityforms.com/purchase-gravity-forms/

Buy it, 40 bucks, it's worth it over and over again.

(Theres also a free demo)

Answer (score 3):

Contact Form 7 is pretty good and free, I used it a lot before I switched to Gravity Forms 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/